# Checking for two consecutive values match of a variable's value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I built a function called `roll()` which handles a roll of a dice. I'm trying to read the value of the roll and check if the roll hit 6 twice in a row so that I can interrupt the player's turn and turn it to the next player.

I can read the dice value alright, I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to check for a 6 twice in a row.

This is my function:

```
 roll = function(){
    if (gamePlaying){
        // 1. Get a random number
        //var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; //1 to 6 randomly
        var dice = 6;

        //2. Display the result
        var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
        diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
        diceDOM.src = 'images/' + 'dice-' + dice + '.png';

        //3. Update the roundScore IF the rolled number is not 1

        // for type coersion, we need to use !== and not !=
        if(dice !== 1) {
            //add score
            roundScore += dice; // same as roundScore = roundScore + dice
            //it outputs to a div of ID = #myId
            document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
        } else {
            alert('Next Player')
            nextPlayer();
        }

        // Is this right?
        for(var i = 1; i >= 2; i++){
            if (dice == 6){
                console.log('sixes');
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Being triggered by a button like this:

```
document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function(){
    roll();

});
```

I loaded the game to this [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/aBLNvr)

P.S. I put a `dice = 6;` under the random function so you don't have to play the game until you get two sixes. Just uncomment it and comment out the dice = math function and you'll get nothing but sixes.

I also put a "Is this right?" comment on top of a for loop. What I mean by that is, " is this the right approach?" Should I keep experimenting with a loop or am I way off already?

And by the way, if 2 sixes do come up, the entire score is deleted which is being passed to the `score[]` But I can do that... I think lol

Many thanks.

Comment: Any values that need to be persisted longer than a single roll (score and a counter on how many sixes have been rolled) need to be stored in variables that have a higher scope than the function. That way, your function can check these values when a new roll has taken place and act accordingly.

Comment: `for(var i = 1; i >= 2; i++){` => What are you trying to do? This is never true

Comment: @Fefux I'm trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, where you make roll() a self invoking function. That way you can store how many times they have rolled a six.

```
roll = (function(){

  var count    = 0;
  var lastRoll = 0;

  return function() {

  if (gamePlaying){

           // 1. Get a random number
           var dice     = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; //1 to 6 randomly
           var thisRoll = dice;

           if(dice === 6) {
              lastRoll  = 6;
              count    += 1;
           } else {
              lastRoll = 0;
              count    = 0;
           }

          if(thisRoll === 6 && lastRoll === 6 && count === 2) {
            alert('You rolled a six twice!');
            lastRoll = 0;
            count    = 0;
            // do your stuff for 2 sixes in a row here!
            return;
           }

        //2. Display the result
        var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
        diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
        diceDOM.src = 'http://sitedev.online/repo/' + 'dice-' + dice + '.png';

        //3. Update the roundScore IF the rolled number is not 1

        // for type coersion, we need to use !== and not !=
        if(dice !== 1) {
            //add score
            roundScore += dice; // same as roundScore = roundScore + dice
            //it outputs to a div of ID = #myId
            document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
            console.log(dice);
        } else {
            alert('Next Player')
            nextPlayer();
        }
    }

  }

})();
```

Comment: This is very good, but I think something is wrong. When I try it with the random function passed into the dice variable it seems like I get the alert for 2 sixes sporadically. Sometimes in a single click. Could it be that it's saving the first six and waiting for the next one and then alerting me of 2 sixes? The alert should happen only when the sixes are in consecutive rolls.

Comment: I know what the issue is. It's checking to see if a six is rolled twice, but it also checks it if it isn't consecutive!

Comment: so if you roll a 6, then a 5, then a 6 you will still get the alert!

Comment: yeah, that's not exactly what I need. I need it to happen consecutively.

Comment: Don't have time to tinker it right now but i'll have a look later! It just needs a minor adjustment

Comment: this problem is from udemy.com. The hint they gave me was: saving a previous roll and the current roll to independent variables and then you can compare to see if they are both sixes. The comparison doesn't sound too hard but saving a roll to a variable and the next one to the a new variable is what has me confused

Comment: I initially thought you could save the entire function to a variable, hence why I saved it to roll. But how do I identify the second run of the function and save it to a nextRoll variable? I'm stomped

Comment: Hey check out the edit, should work for you now! Tested in your code pen so should be good to go!

Comment: This is a much better solution. One thing I forgot is of course, if player 1 rolls a six and holds it there, and player 2 starts with a roll 6 on his turn,  he loses his turn. But, you know what man, It's not like this is a school assignment or a client's project. The point was to learn how to do this. And you've worked hard enough. Thank you for time. I'll learn from this. Thank yo so much

Answer (score 1):

Just for the heck of it, you don't need any global or outside vars to do this. The trick is, remember that functions are objects. You can read and write properties to them; you can even entirely change a function from within the function (which is the trick to an old JS singleton pattern).

Here's an example. If you say feed it "true", it will update the "last" reference values and return two random dice rolls. If you feed it "false", it will NOT update the previous reference values until you pass in true again (but it still returns a fresh roll). That way, you can keep rolling, hold the initial value, and compare it to a new second value all you want.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var rollfunc = function ( updateLast ) {
        var d1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        var d2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        if ( updateLast ) {
            rollfunc.d1 = d1;
            rollfunc.d2 = d2;
        }

        return { 
            dice1 : d1, 
            dice2 : d2, 
            bothsixes : ( ( d1 + d2 === 6 ) && ( rollfunc.d1 + rollfunc.d2 === 6 ) ) 
        }; 
    }

    var result = rollfunc ( true );
    // If you pass in true then d1, d2, and rollfunc.d1, rollfunc.d2 will always be the same
    console.log ( "Reference updated: ", result, "d1 = " + rollfunc.d1, ", d2 = " + rollfunc.d2 );
    var result = rollfunc ( false );
    // If you pass in false, the reference won't change, but the new roll will, you can compare the two
    console.log ( "Reference left alone: ", result, "d1 = " + rollfunc.d1, ", d2 = " + rollfunc.d2 );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this might be overly academic, but it's useful to know JS can do this.

Comment: Tim, thank you for this. Don't worry about it being overly academic. It's not a "college" thing. It's an online tutorial from udemy.com.  I haven't tested this to see if it works but I will go through it. Plus one buddy

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this game. But I'm new to JavaScript, and currently on a similar project from udemy.com.

Here's a solution I found that apparently works. I verified it on your CodePen, too.

```
document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
if (gamePlaying) {

    // 1. Get a random number
    dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; //1 to 6 randomly
    thisRoll = dice;

    if (dice === 6) {
        lastRoll = 6;
        count += 1;
    } else {
        lastRoll = 0;
        count = 0;
    }

    if (thisRoll === 6 && lastRoll === 6 && count === 2) {
        alert('You rolled a six twice!');
        lastRoll = 0;
        count = 0;
        nextPlayer();
        // do your stuff for 2 sixes in a row here!
        return;
    }

    //2. Display result
    var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
    diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
    diceDOM.src = 'http://sitedev.online/repo/' + 'dice-' + dice + '.png';


    //3. Update round score if the rollled number was not a 1
    if (dice !== 1) {
        //Add score
        roundScore += dice;
        //roundScore = roundScore + dice
        document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;

    } else {
        nextPlayer();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on the same problem. Found another solution on udemy. Hope it helps...

```
var lastRoll;
document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Generating a random variable
    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    // Check for two consecutive 6's'
    if ( dice === 6 && lastDice === 6) {
        //If consecutive 6's code goes here
    } 
    lastRoll = dice;
});
```